# Angularjs access attribute in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am very new in AngularJs, I want to create a Select list and when the choose one option open the correspondent file.
This is my main.html

```
<select ng-model="model.options" >
  <option value="1"> 1</option>
  <option value="2"> 2</option>
  <option value="3"> 3</option>
</select>


<div ng-show="model != null" class="main" ng-controller = "TestCtrl">
   <li class="artist cf" ng-repeat="item in data">
      <div class="info">
        <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

this is the controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}]);
```

Someone can help me doing something like this ?

```
$http.get('data-$SELECTED-OPTION-VALUE.json').success(function(data) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should place your `ng-controller` attribute in a higher order tag, like the `<body>` or a wrapping `<div>`. This is necesary so all your related HTML elements like your `<select>` and your `<div>` share the same controller's scope.

Second, the binding in your select is wrong. Instead of `ng-model="model.options"` you need to use a variable declared in your controller's scope. Ej:

**In your controller:**

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedValue = 0;
}
```

**In your HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedValue" >
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-show="model != null" class="main">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, you can bind your data loading to a button click or something like that, calling a scope function in which you will have available the `selectedValue` scope variable. Ej:

**In your HTML, inside `<div class="wrap">`:**

```
<input type="button" value="load data" ng-click="loadData()" />
```

**In your controller:**

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedValue = 0;

  ...

  $scope.loadData = function() {
    $http.get('data-' + $scope.selectedValue + '.json').success(function(data) {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure the select is *inside* the element controlled by `TestCtrl`, and not outside.

Then, use `ng-change`, in order to call a function each time the selected value changes:

```
<select ng-model="model.options" ng-change="displayData()">
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.displayData = function() {
     $http.get('data-' + $scope.model.options + '.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
     });
};
```

Note that the naming is bad here: why name `model.options` (plural form) a variable containing *one* selected option?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) event on each list item like this

```
<li class="artist cf" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="select(item)>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
  </div>
</li>
```

Then you could have a function in your `TestCtrl` which handles the `onclick` handler

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;

  $scope.select = function (item) {
       // do something with the item here.    
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood me. I want to load the corresponding data.json for the selected option. If option 1 is selected then data1.json.... After I just want to print the result, I don't need ng-click there

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how I misunderstood your first answer, you could `watch` your model.options and do the query based on that

```
$scope.$watch(model.options, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    getData(newValue); // newValue will be 1,2 or 3 in your case
};

var getData = function (value) {
    $http.get('data' + value + '.json') // you get it from here
}
```